# Google Maps only display name of place, no map layer in Android Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, maps

I'm learning display google map in Android now. Just a very simple application for display google map in main activity.

Map display has no problem in real hardware(Samsung Galaxy C5). But it cannot display map layer in Android emulator.

I tried API 19, 23 and 25, same result. Please see screenshot. Anyone know why? Thanks.

[Screenshot: map in api 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bapz.jpg)

[Screenshot: error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F13QP.jpg)

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.zhongjiefan.mapsapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.example.zhongjiefan.mapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.zhongjiefan.mapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permissions.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
              android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
               android:value="--removed--"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.zhongjiefan.mapsapp.MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.zhongjiefan.mapsapp;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(googleServicesAvailable()) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Perfect!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initMap();

    } else {

        // No google maps layout
    }
}

private void initMap() {
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

public boolean googleServicesAvailable() {
    GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int isAvailable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        return true;
    }
    else if(api.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isAvailable, 0);
        dialog.show();

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connection to play services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. 
I had your problem too, when I created my project everything was fine and I had my map that working absolutely OK. But after 2 days suddenly my map in emulator got ruined and it showed location name without any layer of map in back, and when I clicked on map or touch it with mouse, the emulator closed. On phone with apk file everything was fine and map worked fine.
When I remoted from another PC to my PC and ran again the program, everything be OK and worked correctly. try this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an emulator with Google API support.
So Create a new emulator as follow
When you create the AVD, select a "Google API" target. The API level would be whatever you want it to be. There are no APKs to install. You need to download the "Google APIs" in the SDK Manager first if you don't have those installed.

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know the root cause. But once I changed a computer and run it. It works fine. Maybe it's caused by graphical card driver or other things.